# Autoware Mission Planning, Client has wrong datatype version: datatype/md5sum

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to launch mission planning node for San Francisco data launch files, I end up getting this error:

```
Error: Client [/rivz_1563460306167327804] wants topic /local_trajectories to have datatype/md5sum [visualization_msgs/MarkerArray/d155b9ce5188fbaf89745847fd5882d7], but our version has [autoware_msgs/LaneArray/23abb100bdfa4ee58530bb628c974c2a]. Dropping connection.
```

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328890/autoware-mission-planning,-client-has-wrong-datatype-version:-datatype/md5sum/) by [hdossaji94](https://answers.ros.org/users/43853/hdossaji94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It means they were compiled with different versions of the message files. When the message files are compiled they make a MD5 hash in case those message definitions change to make sure they're able to be decoded correctly by the receiver. You need to have both programs using the right set of definitions installed.

Edit: More info, sorry I scanned over the types and missed the fact they are literally different messages.

Ok, so what you're trying to do here is expose a topic of type autoware_msgs/LaneArray on the topic /local_trajectories. You've created the data vis plugin for local_trajectories to have type MarkerArray, which is not LaneArray. Your issue is that you have the wrong messages being broadcast on that topic. You need to create the correct plugin visualization to see the LaneArray (does autoware provide?)

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hdossaji94](https://answers.ros.org/users/43853/hdossaji94/) on 2019-07-18**:
Thanks for the quick response!
Would you mind giving me some insight into the steps involved to do this?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-07-18**:
See update in answer, you're publishing the wrong message type on that topic to be visualized as a MarkerArray.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into the same problem and below is how I resolved it.
The problem is caused by Rviz config file having the wrong configuration for local_trajectories.

With the latest version of Autoware, topic for Rviz is named `/local_trajectories_gen_rviz` (see here:  https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/core_planning/-/blob/master/op_local_planner/nodes/op_trajectory_generator/op_trajectory_generator_core.cpp#L41).
So open your rviz config file and find the entry for `local_trajectories` and change it to `local_trajectories_gen_rviz`. This should resolve the above error.

---

Originally posted by [SenRamakri](https://answers.ros.org/users/54895/senramakri/) with karma: 33 on 2020-05-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous62924](https://answers.ros.org/users/62924/anonymous62924/) on 2020-12-01**:
Thank you! This has solved my issue.